# startActivityForResult not starting second activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a LocationActivity that gets the GPS location from the Google API. I need to use this data in my MainActivity. I am using startActivityForResult to accomplish this, but my LocationActivity never executes and my app crashes when I try to access the data.

Here is are some relevant snippets from **MainActivity.java**:

```
public void onUpdateClick(View v) { //button click handler which starts the process

    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LocationActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, GPS_DATA_REQUEST);

    byte[] data = latitude.getBytes(); //app crashes here because latitude is null
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == GPS_DATA_REQUEST) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            latitude=data.getStringExtra("latitude");
        }
    }
}
```

And here are relevant snippets from **LocationActivity.java**:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest,this);


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        latitude = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
    }

    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("latitude",latitude);
    setResult(LocationActivity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    finish();
}
```

And my Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/label_broadcast">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".LocationActivity">
    </activity>
</application>
```

I have referred to many threads and the Android activity/intent documentation but have not been able to solve this. Any help/suggestions would be appreciated. I have tried to provide only the relevant information. Thanks!

Comment: post your logcat

Comment: you cannot expect to get result just immediately after `startActivityForResult`. The result will be received in `onActivityResult`. Android basics

Comment: @SMR say You can't get result immediately after `startActivityForResult`.You need to receive your latitude in `onActivityResult`, so do other code in 'onActivityResult` method once you receive the latitude else do request again for get latitude.

Comment: I don't understand why are you starting while activity for just getting `latitude`?

Comment: just replace 'setResult(LocationActivity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);' with 'setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);' .

Comment: @Shailesh, I do capture my result in onActivityResult on the line latitude=data.getStringExtra("latitude"); My problem is that my app never enters onActivityResult in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Move the code in LocationActivity from onConnected to onStart. startActivityForResult invokes the onStart lifecycle method.

Answer (score 0):

You cant used

```
byte[] data = latitude.getBytes();
```

At time of activity start latitude will be null

Update your code with this.

```
    public void onUpdateClick(View v) { //button click handler which starts the process

    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LocationActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, GPS_DATA_REQUEST);


}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == GPS_DATA_REQUEST) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            latitude=data.getStringExtra("latitude");
byte[] data = latitude.getBytes();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My app never enters onActivityResult. I have tried all the suggestions everyone has given and am still getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

It not looks good.. Once it is connected to location service it looks like you finish second activity.. Then it will kill your second activity and again resumes your first activity. Here, you need to change logic in `LocationActivity`

Answer (score 0):

You can try change LocationActivity.java

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent(LocationActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
returnIntent.putExtra("latitude",latitude);
setResult(LocationActivity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, but this did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is on LocationActivity class on line 
setResult(LocationActivity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);

Actually you need
setResult(GPS_DATA_REQUEST, returnIntent);

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I hope you will get you solution.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public void onUpdateClick(View v) { //button click handler which starts the process

    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LocationActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, GPS_DATA_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == GPS_DATA_REQUEST) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            latitude=data.getStringExtra("latitude");

            if(latitude != null)
               byte[] data = latitude.getBytes(); 
            else
              //do request again for latitude.
        }
    }
}
```

You need to set result in you **LocationActivity.java**

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent(LocationActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
returnIntent.putExtra("latitude",latitude);
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. My app never enters onActivityResult. Why would this be?

Comment: Please check my updated answer, i have removed 'finish()` method. I think you do something wrong because above code is worked for.So please tell me actual flow of your process.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Then I realized that I've initialized and declared my views before the second activity's `OnCreate` method is invoked. Putting declaration into `OnCreate` as shown below solved the problem.

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity{

// View declaration, put your views here
TextView mTextViewExample;
EditText mEditTextExample;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2);
        setTitle(R.string.title_activity2);

        // View initialization, put your views here
        mTextViewExample = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewExample);
        mEditTextExample = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextExample);

    }
}
```